# Factorization of a smooth function problem

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be a smooth function  such that $f(0) = 0$ and $\nabla f(0) = O$. It is possible to factorize $f$ as $f(x) = g(x) h(x)$ where  $g,h :\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are smooth and $g(0)=h(0)=0$?

I did not  manage to conclude anything neither in the case when $f\geq 0$, where seems natural to define $g = h = \sqrt[]{f}$ but as shown in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105438/square-root-of-a-positive-c-infty-function $\sqrt{f}$ can be non smooth.

Comment: what happens if you make $g(x)=f(x)^{1/3}$ and $h(x)=f(x)^{2/3}$? (edit: ah nevermind, same issue....)

Answer (score 0):

Write out the def. of derivative at $x=0 $, for any direction $\ \vec e$:
$$\frac{f(0+h\vec e) - f(o) - [0](\vec e)}{h} \longrightarrow 0$$
But the LHS equals
$$\frac{f(h\vec e)}{h}:=g(h\vec e) $$
$$g(0):=0$$
Now, we do have that
$$\forall h, f(h\vec e)= h.g(h\vec e)$$

$h$ seen as function is already nice: smooth, and zero at zero. So, if you prove that $g$ defined above is smooth at $0$ then you're done (nonzero points follow from smoothness of $f$.)

I think if you take derivatives, you can prove that all exist at 0, which finishes this construction.

Comment: I don't understand how you define $g$ over the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$. Following your  ideas, if also $f''(0) = O$ then $f(x) = o(\vert \vert x \vert \vert^2)$ so we can decompose $f(x) = \vert \vert x \vert \vert^2 \frac{f(x)}{\vert \vert x \vert \vert^2}$ and we are done. Unfortunately if $f$ is only  $ o(\vert \vert x \vert \vert)$, then $\frac{f(x)}{\vert \vert x \vert \vert} $ is $C^0$ but may be not smooth (for example $f(x) = \vert \vert x \vert \vert^2$).

Comment: Written in a different way $\frac{f(h\vec e)}{h}:=g(h\vec e)$ means, for given $x \in R^n$, $g(x)=\frac {f(x)}{\|x\|}$, which is $O(\|x\|)$ by definition of differentiability.

Comment: But you're right. $\|x\|$ is not smooth at zero. My bad.
However, my feeling is that the answer is in the difference quotients, because the only assumption is that of differentiability at 0.